# iPhone 4 MD439LL

Tags: iphone, podcasts

I attempted to open my Podcast app and it looked as if it was working, ie. screen went dark and then back to app icon, w/out opening the app.  This repeats at every attempt. 
 The same day, hour & event I noticed my FaceTime & iCloud icons in Settings "gray" and inaccessible. Hard to believe it's coincidence. 
 Please someone tell me I just switched something the wrong way and didn't notice. 
 I hadn't been in settings or any such. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a software problem. Does your wifi work?

Try doing reset all settings on the phone. If that fails, next step is restoring the OS on your phone and and updating to the newest version. If/when you do this, do NOT reuse an old backup, as it may put the problem back on to your phone.

Comment: Thanks Vitalydotn, hopin' it was going to come to that. But sounds like my route. Much appreciation.